# Tomcat server is not starting

Tags: security, tomcat, servlets

I am using jdbc in form based authentication but when i add realm tag with connection properties in server.xml file, tomcat is not starting:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
    connectionName="system"
    connectionPassword="system"
    userTable="users" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
    userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="rolename"/>
```

Comment: *where* do you add this snippet and what does the *log file* say?

Comment: i uncomented existing Realm tag and added new one in server.xml thats it nothing did else

Comment: second part of my initial question: What does the logfile say? Bonus question: Did you add the oracle jdbc driver in tomcat/lib?

Comment: yes i addedd ojdbc6.jar,i am using oracle11g

Comment: do you ignore my question for the log file content on purpose?